# Calling a specific Python version from system function in PHP

Tags: php, python, scripting, hook

At the root of my issue, I am trying to call a Python script from inside a PHP script. I am on a shared server, with multiple versions of Python installed:

```
/usr/bin/python -V ... 2.6
/home/tony/python/python -V ... 2.7
/home/tony/python/Python-3.2/python ... 3.2

echo $PATH ... /home2/tony/python/Python-3.2/
echo $PYTHONPATH... /home2/tony/python/lib/python3.2/site-packages
```

Also I made an alias in Unix:

```
alias python3='/home2/tony/python/Python-3.2/python'
```

Here is the Python script (test.py) contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Python version:', sys.version_info
```

Here is the PHP script (test.php) contents:

```
<?php

$py_script = "test.py";
$py_args = "name1=value1++name2=value2";

system('python ' . $py_script . ' ' . $py_args, $retval);

// $retval will have a trailing 0 or 1 at the end

$retval = trim($retval, "0 1");

echo $retval;

?>
```

But when I hit test.php in a browser, I still see version 2.6. I don't know what part of my script I have to change to force Python 3.2 above to be used (I need functionality/modules in 3.2 that 2.6 cannot handle). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't you `system('/home2/tony/python/Python-3.2/python')` ? And check `/usr/bin/python3 -V`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your alias as the user the web server is running as (typically www-data on debian or ubuntu)

```
 alias python3='/home2/tony/python/Python-3.2/python'
```

**OR** change your PHP

```
<?php

$py_script = "test.py";
$py_args = "name1=value1++name2=value2";

system('/home/tony/python/Python-3.2/python ' . $py_script . ' ' . $py_args, $retval);

// $retval will have a trailing 0 or 1 at the end

$retval = trim($retval, "0 1");

echo $retval;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much beiller! I couldn't figure out the first recommendation (using the alias as the user) but by putting the full path of the 3.2 version I was able to use that version. I dont know why it didn't work before. Thanks!!